# How to share resources between test and main?

Tags: java, maven, java-8, maven-3

I'm working on a web application.

This is my project structure

```
src/
├── main
│   ├── java
│   ├── resources
│   └── webapp
└── test
    ├── java
    └── resources
```

In my tests I want to call a method from a class in `java` which uses a file in `resources`.

So I want to know how to share my resources between `main` and `test`?

I don't want to copy files to `test-resources` every time I edit them.

I tried SymLink but got an error 'Can't copy to `test-classes` because file does not exist.`

And this is how I access a resource in case it matters

```
class.getResourceAsStream("/data.yml");
```

**EDIT**

---

So, apparently Maven do share resources between main and test by default but it's not the case here.

When I build I can see my resources from `main` under `target/classes` but nothing in `target/test-classes`.

Comment: are you talking files ends with`.properties`?

Comment: @JasonZ No, it's a yaml file but how does it matter? I've edited my question to show how I access them in class.

Answer (score 7):

Files present in `main` are visible in `test`.

So you can put resources on the main tree if necessary for both tests and main.

If the resources are necessary only for the test put them on the test subtree.

Comment: My resources are already there in main but when I build it doesn't get copied to `test-classes`.

Answer (score 3):

With Maven, your files under `src/main/resources` are shared with `src/test/resources` by default. Just put them there and they'll be accessible from the `test` folder as well.

Comment: My resources are already there in main but when I build it doesn't get copied to `test-classes`.

Comment: Hey, you think you can take a look at my edit? I'm not sure what I'm missing. I've search everywhere and couldn't find anything.

Comment: They're in different class loaders. This is why you should use `MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("data.yml")` instead of what you wrote.

Comment: The resources aren't in test classpath. It should be present in test-classes but it isn't there.

Comment: They should not. The difference is about classpaths, not folders. If you use files directly then yes you'll have issues. Not if you use resources as I wrote.

Comment: I am using just how you mentioned. But I get `/target/test-classes/data.yml (No such file or directory)`. My code is in main. I'm just calling a method from test.